# Is it possible to call a pre-set palette of colors instead of a standard one in input type?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a color selector,
where the color is chosen from a standard built in system palette.

Is it possible to make a finite color set of my own choice and then use it as the palette in the input color method?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <!-- CLICK TO CHANGE COLOR -->
    <input type="color" value="#e73d18">

    <!-- Image Credit -->


    </body>
    </html>
```

style.css:

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://gecko.sashaz.com/green_Gecko.jpg)no-repeat; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
}

input {
    /* removes default styling from input color element */

    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    /* makes input (color swatch) 100% size of container */

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* mix blend mode makes the color of the swatch alter the image behind it. */

    mix-blend-mode: hue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* removes default styling from input color element */

::-webkit-color-swatch {
    border: none;
}

::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
}

::-moz-color-swatch,
::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0;
}
/* Image Credit */

a {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    color: skyblue;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: _"Is it possible to make a finite color set of my own choice and then use it as the palette in the input color method?"_ Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? What is expected result ? Limit color selection options ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, how to limit them to exactly my choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining accepted colors within an array , using `onfocus` event to check if selected color is valid , if not , sett color to `#ffffff`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");

var colors = ["#e73d18", "#cc5522", "#bb7788", "#dd3344"];

input.onfocus = function(e) {
  if (colors.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
    this.value = "#ffffff";
    this.focus()
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://gecko.sashaz.com/green_Gecko.jpg)no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  /* removes default styling from input color element */
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  /* makes input (color swatch) 100% size of container */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* mix blend mode makes the color of the swatch alter the image behind it. */
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* removes default styling from input color element */

::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}
::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
::-moz-color-swatch,
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Image Credit */

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: skyblue;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#e73d18">
```

---

alternatively , using `datalist` , `onchange` event

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");

var colors = ["#e73d18", "#cc5522", "#bb7788", "#dd3344"];

input.onchange = function(e) {
  if (colors.indexOf(this.value) === -1) {
    this.value = "#ffffff";
    this.focus()
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://gecko.sashaz.com/green_Gecko.jpg)no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
input {
  /* removes default styling from input color element */
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  /* makes input (color swatch) 100% size of container */
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* mix blend mode makes the color of the swatch alter the image behind it. */
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* removes default styling from input color element */

::-webkit-color-swatch {
  border: none;
}
::-webkit-color-swatch-wrapper {
  padding: 0;
}
::-moz-color-swatch,
::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}
::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Image Credit */

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  color: skyblue;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input list="colors" type="color" value="#e73d18" />
</label>
<datalist id="colors">
  <option value="#e73d18"></option>
  <option value="#cc5522"></option>
  <option value="#bb7788"></option>
  <option value="#dd3344"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I add the script in the body before the input then?

Comment: I have just changed, it works! Very much appreciate your help!

Comment: Can I ask one more question, please. How to position this selctor so it pops up under the coursor and not in the top left corner?

Comment: @AlexandraSerebrennikova At chromium color selector displays below viewport ; not certain if dialog position can be adjusted using native HTML5 ?, though see http://jscolor.com/examples/ , where appear color picker position can be adjusted using plugin ?

Comment: yes, will have a look. The best I could come up is only adjusting a position of input method in css a bit:  position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;, but it is not fair solution, just to get it from the corner.

Comment: yes, it helps to adjust it a bit better, but overall turns out the palette can't overlap with the area of input.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with only HTML, but you can definitely achieve this with JavaScript.  Check out https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/
Show Palette Only looks like what you want.